# Replying to a message in thread using a slash command

Tags: java, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Can we use a slash command to send a message in thread(replying to some previous message) in a channel?

Answer (score 1):

To post a threaded reply, you'll need original message's timestamp.

 The payload generated by 'Slash Command' interactivity can't provide you that.

Instead you should use '[Message Shortcuts](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/shortcuts/using#message_shortcuts)' for this implementation.

 Then use [chat.PostMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) and add original message's timestamp as [`thread_ts`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#arg_thread_ts) argument.